# QGIS copy and paste error: "no features could be successfully pasted"

Tags: qgis

What does this error message mean, and how can you get more info on what might be the cause?

"no features could be successfully pasted"

(or more generally, not all of the selected items could be successfully pasted)

(I'm using QGIS 2.3 (build 422148c) on Vista Home Basic 32bit)

Seems like it's probably a problem with the source data; what's a good way to track that down?  If just modifying some of the source metadata would let the paste operation work, it would beat trying to reproduce the source data by hand in the target layer.

Thanks

UDPATE: looking at the metadata for successfully copied objects vs the object that dies, the one that won't copy has no firstX, firstY, lastX, lastY keys in the (Derived) section where the ones that paste successfully do have those keys with appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved in QGIS 2.4.0; looks like it was a multi-part line vs single-part line copy and paste issue, I'm not conversant on the details:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10672